# TextViews not in the correct space In LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a LinearLayout that has 2 TextViews. At the moment the first TextView should be on the top and in the center, whereas it is actually displayed on the left?

The second TextView should be on the bottom and in the center, whereas it is being displayed on the right?

I have been trying using layout_gravity and gravity but I  just can’t get them to be shown correctly? Any help appreciated.

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"

    android:background="@drawable/frame_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.72">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSpaceRowsVal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="top|center"

        android:text="TOP 1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="75dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="608dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:text="Bottom 2"
        android:textColor="#000"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="60dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="584dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.

Answer (score 2):

Your orientation is lining elements horizontally, where it looks like you want vertically.  In your LinearList change the orientation from this:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to this:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Then update the gravity of the TextView, so its centered.  Change this in the TextViews:

```
android:layout_gravity="top|center"
```

to:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Comment: Many thanks - really appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

use this code on LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSpaceRowsVal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TOP 1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="75dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="608dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Bottom 2"
        android:textColor="#000"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="60dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="584dp" />
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Really appreciate the great help!